# number of k when build a yai object in yaiImpute package

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the best number of nearest neighbor to use in mahalanobis method in `yai` function offered by `yaImpute` package (1.0-19). I tried to run the `yai` function with 'mal' method with different number of k:

```
mal<-yai(x=x,y=y,method="mahalanobis", k=5, noTrgs= FALSE, nVec=NULL, pVal=.05, ann=F)

mal<-yai(x=x,y=y,method="mahalanobis", k=20, noTrgs= FALSE, nVec=NULL, pVal=.05, ann=F)
```

But, when I'm looking the rmsd (root mean square distance) of each, there are exactly the same. The process found effectively the number of `k` that I asked (when I print the 'mal' object), but it seems like it does not use them.

My aim is to use `AsciiGridImpute` function to impute values on my entire map. But I don't understand what is the utility of the `k` number in my `yai` object. How the `AscciGridImpute` use them?

Thank you

Sorry for my bad english!!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found why the RMSD was the same whatever the number of k used in the `yai` object.

The function `rmsd.yai` called automatically an other function call `impute.yai`. That function is supposed to allow methods as `mean` or `dstWeighted` to compute the imputed values for continuous variables. The use of these methods changed effectively the rmsd values depending on the number of k.

But the automatically call of this function (`impute.yai`) compute imputed values with the default method:`closest`. So only one k is used.

I think it's the same thing that happen with the function `AsciiGridImpute`.